# Multiple Google Vision OCR requests at once?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

According to the [Google Vision documentation](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate), the maximum number of image files per request is 16. [Elsewhere](https://cloud.google.com/vision/quotas), however, I'm finding that the maximum number of requests per minute is as high as 1800. Is there any way to submit that many requests in such a short period of time from a single machine? I'm using curl on a Windows laptop, and I'm not sure how to go about submitting a second request before waiting for the first to finish almost a minute later (if such a thing is possible).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Vision batch OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564632/google-vision-batch-ocr)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to request 1800 images, you can group 16 images per request (1800/16) you will need 113 request.

On the other hand, if the limit is 1800 requests per minute and each request can contain 16 images, then you can process 1800 * 16 = 28800 images per minute.

Please consider that docs says: [These limits apply to each Google Cloud Platform Console project](https://cloud.google.com/vision/quotas#request_quotas) and are shared across all applications and IP addresses using that project. So it doesn't matter if requests are sent from a single o many machines.

Cloud Vision can receive parallel requests, so your app should be prepared to manage this amount of requests/responses. You may want to check [this example](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-text#detecting_text_in_a_local_image) and then use threads in your preferred programming language for sending/receiving parallel operations.