# Perform Text Detection on Multiple PDFs on Google Vision API

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

As per the documentation, the API is set up in a way that you can only detect text on a single pdf file. How could I be able to perform image detection on multiple pdf files in the same Cloud bucket? I'm using Python as my main language.

Comment: How about? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732768/how-to-annotate-multiple-images-from-a-single-call-using-googles-vision-api-py

Comment: and --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585778/multiple-google-vision-ocr-requests-at-once

Comment: I found them while searching but they are meant for text extraction from an image, while i'm trying to do it on different pdfs. But I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question and refer to the PDF, you talking about multi page pdf or different pdfs ?

Comment: here- > https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/file-small-batch#vision_batch_annotate_files-python 
small batch files for pages in same pdf

Comment: No, I meant different pdfs.